# Graph Not Changing Colors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-manipulation, gganimate

I wrote the following procedure in R:

- Start with a data frame called "giraffe" data
- Sample 30% of this data and label it "sample"
- Create a histogram for this data, and color the areas of this histogram that were "sampled" as one color, and the other rows another color
- Repeat this process 100 times and make an animation of this process

  ```
  library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(gganimate)

    giraffe_data <- data.frame( a = abs(rnorm(1000,17,10)), b = abs(rnorm(1000,17,10)))

    results <- list()



    for( i in 1:100) 

    {

        giraffe_data_i <- giraffe_data 
        a_i <- c("sample", "not_sampled")
        aa_i <- as.factor(sample(a_i, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7)))
        giraffe_data_i $col = cut(giraffe_data_i$a, c(-Inf, 17, Inf))
        giraffe_data_i$sample <- aa_i
        giraffe_data_i$iteration <- i + 1



        results[[i]] <- giraffe_data_i

    }

    results
    results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)




    animate(
      ggplot(results_df, aes(x=a, fill = col)) + 
      geom_histogram(binwidth=1) +  
      scale_fill_manual(breaks = levels(results_df$col), values = c('blue', 'red')) +
      transition_states(iteration, state_length = 0.2) +
      labs(title = "Group: {closest_state}"),
      fps = 25)
  ```

[image]

But for some reason, this graph does not change colors in the animation.

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks

**Note**: I was able to get the colors to change with the following code:

```
animate(
    ggplot(results_df, aes(x=a, color = sample)) + 
        geom_histogram(fill="white", position="dodge")+  
        transition_states(iteration, state_length = 0.2) +
        labs(title = "Group: {closest_state}"),
    fps = 5)
```

[image]

But this shows the two colors as two separate "groups". I want there to be only one "group", but there to be different colors within this one "group". Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I find it easier to do transformations of the data upstream of gganimate. So here's an approach of binning the data and counting for each iteration, and then plotting as a normal column geom.

```
library(tidyverse); library(gganimate)
# bins of width 2
bin_wid = 2
results_df_bins <- results_df %>%
  # "col" is set at 17 but my bins are at even #s, so to align 
  #   bins with that I offset by 1
  mutate(a_bin = floor((a + 1)/ bin_wid)*bin_wid) %>%
  count(a_bin, col, sample, iteration) %>%
  mutate(sample = fct_rev(sample)) # put "sample" first

animate(
  ggplot(results_df_bins, aes(x=a_bin, y = n, fill = sample)) + 
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
    transition_states(iteration, state_length = 0.2) +
    labs(title = "Group: {closest_state}"),
  fps = 25, nframes = 500, height = 300)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! I wonder why the blue bars are also not changing colors? I am still working on it! thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: I posted a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69509234/attaching-multiple-graphs-together-in-r

Comment: (also, how do you insert animations into answers on stackoverflow? very cool!)

Comment: When I run the `animate()` line, a GIF is created in the Viewer window of RStudio, which I right-click to save and then add to SO the same way I'd add a PNG, using the add picture icon.