# Attaching Multiple Graphs Together in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, data-visualization

I made the following 3 graphs in R:

```
#create data
a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 1
c = data.frame(a,b,i)
c$col = as.factor(ifelse(c$b>10,"red", "blue"))

a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 2
d = data.frame(a,b,i)
d$col = as.factor(ifelse(d$a>10,"red", "blue"))

a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 3
e = data.frame(a,b,i)
e$col = as.factor(ifelse(e$b>10,"red", "blue"))

   #put all the datasets together (i=1, i=2, i=3)
g = rbind(c,d,e)

 #plot
plot_1 = plot(c$a, type = "h", col = c$col, main = "plot_1, i = 1")
plot_2 = plot(d$a, type = "h", col = d$col, main = "plot_2, i = 2")
plot_3 = plot(e$a, type = "h", col = e$col, main = "plot_3, i = 3")
```

[image]

I am trying to make an "animation" of these graphs : plot_1 -> plot_2 -> plot_3

I was able to do something similar using ggplot2/gganimate:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

animate(
  ggplot(g, aes(x=a)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1) +
  transition_states(i, state_length = 0.2) +
  labs(title = "Group: {closest_state}"),
  fps = 25)
```

[image]

But I am specifically trying to do this using the graphs created with base R. This is because I find the coloring scheme more effective, I can't seem to as clearly show the different colors in the ggplot version as I can with the base R version.

[image]

Can someone please show me how to "animate/attach" these 3 graphs together?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may try in `gifski` animation in a markdown page

````
---
title: "Title"
output: html_document

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
 knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
 ```

## R Markdown

 ```{r data, echo = FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(gifski))
a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 1
c = data.frame(a,b,i)
c$col = as.factor(ifelse(c$b>10,"red", "blue"))

a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
i = 2
d = data.frame(a,b,i)
d$col = as.factor(ifelse(d$a>10,"red", "blue"))

 a = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
 b = abs(rnorm(100,10,10))
 i = 3
 e = data.frame(a,b,i)
 e$col = as.factor(ifelse(e$b>10,"red", "blue"))

#put all the datasets together (i=1, i=2, i=3)
g = rbind(c,d,e)

 lst1 <- list(c, d, e)

 ```


 ```{r, animation.hook="gifski"}
 for (i in seq_along(lst1)) {
  plot(lst1[[i]]$a, type = 'h', col = lst1[[i]]$col,
      main = paste0("plot_", i))
  }
 ```
````

---

Or if we just want to save the file as `gif`

```
library(gifski)
lst1 <- list(c, d, e)
gif_file <- "/path/to/file.gif")
save_gif(
for (i in seq_along(lst1)) {
  plot(lst1[[i]]$a, type = 'h', col = lst1[[i]]$col, main = paste0("plot_", i))
}, gif_file, 1280, 720, res = 144)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! can you please show me how to enter this code? In Rstudio, I clicked "file", "new file", "rmarkdown", "(new) document". Then i copy/pasted your code into the window, then clicked "knit". is this what I am supposed to do? I can now see the animation!

Comment: is there a way to remove the text at the start of the html? R Markdown ## Warning: package 'gifski' was built under R version 4.0.5
for (i in seq_along(lst1)) {
 plot(lst1[[i]]$a, type = 'h', col = lst1[[i]]$col,
     main = paste0("plot_", i))
 }

Comment: @Noob you can wrap with `suppressWarnings` i..e `suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(gifski)))`

Comment: @Noob Yes, in Rstudio, you create a new document, save, and knit (after copy/pasting the same code in my post)

Comment: thank you for all your help! I guess I now have to learn how to use Rmarkdown .... so much to learn. I wish there was a simpler way to just save everything as a gif from the very beginning!

Comment: @Noob You can use `saveGIF` from `animation`

Comment: i opened your output in an internet browser and directly saved it from there! LOL

Comment: @Noob i updated another option with `save_gif` from `gifski` itself

Comment: Suppose I have three plots (p1, p2, p3) ready, can the following code be made to work? library(gifski)
gif_file <- ( "C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/ref.gif")
save_gif((p1, p2, p3), gif_file, 1280, 720, res = 144)

Comment: @Noob You can wrap with `list` i.e. `list(p1, p2, p3)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just tried this code and it gives me a blank output?

Comment: library(gifski)
lst1 <- list(plot_1, plot_2, plot_3)
gif_file <- ("C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/mygif.gif")
save_gif(lst1, gif_file, 1280, 720, res = 144)

Comment: @Noob I haven't tested it, may be it wouldn't work because the base R `plot` output have no return value.  So, it cannot be stored in a object

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for such a solution?

We could use `par()`

With the `par()` function, we could include the option `mfrow=c(nrows, ncols)` to create a matrix of nrows x ncols plots that are filled in by row.

`mfcol=c(nrows, ncols)` fills in the matrix by columns.

```
par(mar = rep(2, 4))
par(mfrow =c(2,3))
plot_1 = plot(c$a, type = "h", col = c$col, main = "plot_1, i = 1")
plot_2 = plot(d$a, type = "h", col = d$col, main = "plot_2, i = 2")
plot_3 = plot(e$a, type = "h", col = e$col, main = "plot_3, i = 3")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But I am trying to make animation out of these graphs. do you know how to do this?